# Twitter data-text attribute is not set using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm using the following button from Twitter to tweet something.

```
<a id="tweet" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Husam" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet it!</a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
```

In my JS file, I'm trying to change data-text attribute using jQuery attr function, so that it tweets what I would like to tweet.

```
$("#tweet").attr("data-text","what I want to tweet");
```

It just doesn't work as expected, I can't change the data-text attribute. Any ideas?

You can see the code here: http://codepen.io/husamp/pen/YyKLze

Comment: Try using `$("#tweet").data('text', 'what you want to tweet')` when you inspect the element `#tweet` the attribute data-text won't show. But when you request it using: `$('#tweet').data('text')` You will see "what you want to tweet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is the `<a id="tweet" ...` is replaced with an iFrame when the Twitter JavaScript is evaluated so your `$(#tweet)` won't actually find any elements so no data attribute is set.

Have a look at the [Tweet Button Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters) and consider using the JavaScript Factory Example to re-create a tweet button every time your quote changes.

The example code from twitter is:

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
        "https:\/\/dev.twitter.com\/web\/tweet-button",
        document.getElementById("tweet-container"),
        {
            size: "large",
            via: "twitterdev",
            related: "twitterapi,twitter",
            text: "PUT UPDATED SHARE TEXT HERE",
            hashtags: "example,demo"
        }
);
```

So on quote change, you'd need to clear the old tweet button and then insert a new one into `#tweet-container`

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set data values using https://api.jquery.com/data/

To set the value

```
$('#tweet').data('text', 'what I want to tweet');
```

To get the value

```
$('#tweet').data('text');
```